# Raw POST data in Perl?

Tags: php, perl, http-post

In PHP, `php://input` enables to read the raw request body data, which is what I need in this case. However the rest of the server-side backbone is all written in PERL, so I tried to find the alternative to `php://input` -- I couldn't.

### Short question:

How can one get the raw POST data (*request body*) in Perl? (the CGI variable showed absolutely nothing).

Thanks!

Comment: is this post what you need?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908113/how-can-i-get-the-entire-request-body-with-cgi-pm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the CGI module's docs,

> If POSTed data is not of type application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data, then the POSTed data will not be processed, but instead be returned as-is in a parameter named POSTDATA. To retrieve it, use code like this:
>
> ```
> my $data = $query->param('POSTDATA');
> ```

Comment: Yep, that should do it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, I have a tiny question: is this binary-safe? I'm POSTing an array buffer from JavaScript, and I plan to write it to a file from PERL (it's raw PCM audio samples).

Comment: @Abody97: It should be. However if you're on Windows, you have to take care to open the file in binary mode.

Comment: `binmode` can be necessary on all systems. Just do `binmode($fh)` after you open the output file.

Comment: @ikegami - Your answer leads me to another 2 questions: **(1)** What if one of the parameters has name `POSTDATA` - how CGI handles such case? **(2)** How can we get raw POST data for Content-Type of *multipart/form-data* to be able find boundaries and read binary files such as PDF?

Comment: @Ωmega, 1) I don't know. 2) CGI.pm handles form-data just as well as x-www-form-urlencoded. File fields are returned as a file handle. Search the docs for "upload"

Comment: @ikegami - Why not to read **raw** data from STDIN before `CGI` does? *(see my answer below)*

Comment: Don't you have to place it in a BEGIN block before `use CGI;` (so it gets executed before CGI.pm reads it), or am I remembering wrong?  Anyway, just it's just a whole lot more complicated than `my $data = $query->param('POSTDATA');`.